# How I get a value after running a mutation?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, knex.js

How do I use knex (postgres), graphql and apollo?
Are there any examples? I have found nothing.

Well on my case: In the mutations for users (createUser) the data is written to the Postgres DB, but I don't get any data, although I return it. With MongoDB everything was easier, but I don't want to use NoSQL DB

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const token = require('../../../helpers/token');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const knex = require('../../../db/knex');
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

module.exports = {
    createUser: async (parent, args, { user, pubsub }) => {
        
        const newUser = await knex.insert({
            id: uuidv4(),
            ...args.data
        })
            .into(`user`)
            .returning('*');


            pubsub.publish('user created', {
                user: newUser
            });
        return {
            user: { newUser },
            token: token.generate(newUser, '1h'),
        };
};
```

Comment: probably you should just `return newUser;` as it's already an object matching mutation return type (structure)

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. You should debug it.